# Find possible bases of an operation

Tags: number-systems

If I have the following operation: $$\sqrt{41}=5 $$ how can I find possible bases?I thought the problem like this: $$4a+1=5_a*5_a$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$41_a=4\cdot a + 1$  so if you want the square root of this to be $5$ you need $a=6$.